# rubymine commit failed with errors

Tags: ruby, git, commit, conflict, rubymine

After pulling from main master, encountering a conflict and resolving conflict.

I'm working in a sub-folder of the main project repo (on automated tests) and so generally don't have to worry about conflicts. It seems however that every time a conflict is encountered and fixed, where I attempt to commit the pulled files RubyMine gives me this error message and won't allow anything to be done to resolve. I've previously taken a new fork from the GitHub main and manually merged in my own lost commits but it's happened again.

I can't find any reference to this dialog on searching the web and our TA has investigated the issue, concluding that it may be a RubyMine bug. I'm continuing my search for relevant info but aside from poring through the bugs in http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY (which I have now done with no relevant issues found) I can't see where any leads might come from.

Latest version of RM (6.0.3) running on Macbook Pro (Mavericks)

RubyMine was used to resolve the conflicts; git status shows only the pulled files I'm now trying to commit as tracked and uncommitted - I have untracked files managed in a gitignore file

The dialog says:

> Commit
>
> Commit failed with errors

With error message displayed in terminal:

> Error: Error executing git commit --only -F
>
> [list of files I attempted to commit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
Goto Tools -> Open terminal
```

Use this command

```
git status
```

Then add untracked files

```
git add .
```

Commit changes like this

```
git commit -i * -m "commit message"
```

If you still have errors please post the error. You can see the Version control logs at the bottom of rubymine

Comment: that has successfully completed the commit; in this case i've already killed the fork and opened a new one but have this for the future - had to look up the -i * reference: "-i
--include
Before making a commit out of staged contents so far, stage the contents of paths given on the command line as well. This is usually not what you want unless you are concluding a conflicted merge." << please could i ask you for a note on what this means, as i don't feel i understand what the problem was nor what this solution does

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Rubymine to resolve the conflicts?  If not, it's possible RubyMine has kept stale state of the filesystem and is reporting the errors because of this.

What does `git status .` tell you in your working directory?  Is your current tree clean, or do you have unmerged changes?